# VB .NET Guardar imagen de un PictureBox en una base de datos

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2016

Estoy en medio de un **proyecto WinForms** que me servirá como base para proyectos futuros, y mientras investigaba me topé con un problema.

Deseo poder **guardar la imagen** mostrada en un **PictureBox** despues de haberla obtenido y mostrado en la mismo con un **OpenFileDialog**.

Por el momento para las pruebas uso **SQL Server 2016 LocalDB**, pero deseo tener poca fricción para cambiar entre **MySQL** o **SQLite** segun necesite.

El código que actualmente tengo es este:

```
'Estructura de la Tabla en la que deseo almacenar la información
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Programas]
(
    [ID] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Programa] VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    [WebSite] VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    [Instalado] BIT NOT NULL,
    [Imagen] VARBINARY(MAX) NULL,
    [Fecha] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Hora] TIME NOT NULL
)

'Clase para conectar con la base de datos y realizar las consultas
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class CRUD
    Dim Cadena As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf; Integrated Security=True"
    Protected Conectar As New SqlConnection(Cadena)
    
    Sub Consulta(ByVal Tabla As DataGridView, ByVal SQL As String)
        Try
            Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conectar)
            Dim DT As New DataTable
            DA.Fill(DT)
            Tabla.DataSource = DT
        Catch ex As Exception
            EMess = ex.Message
            MessageBox.Show(EMess)
        End Try
    End Sub
    
    Sub Operaciones(ByVal Tabla As DataGridView, ByVal SQL As String)
        Conectar.Open()
        Try
            Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(SQL, Conectar)
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            EMess = ex.Message
            MessageBox.Show(EMess)
        End Try
        Conectar.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

'Clase del Form donde están los eventos para realizar las consultas del CRUD
Imports System.IO
Public Class Inicio
    Dim CDB As New CRUD
    Dim DataDate As String
    Dim DataHour As String
    Dim Imagen As String
    'Consultas SQL
    Dim SQL As String
    
    'Boton para abrir OpenFileDialog y asignar imagen a PictureBox
    Private Sub ButSPict_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButSPict.Click
        Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog
        OpenFile.Filter = "Archivos de imagen (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png, *.bmp)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp"
        OpenFile.Title = "Seleccionar imagen"
        OpenFile.FilterIndex = 1
        OpenFile.RestoreDirectory = True
        If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            PBxLogo.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFile.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub
    
    'Convirtiendo la imagen del PictureBox en objeto MemoryStream, y despues en arreglo de Bytes
    Sub ConveImg()
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream
        PBxLogo.Image.Save(MS, PBxLogo.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim Img() As Byte = MS.ToArray()
    End Sub
    
    'Proceso para SQL INSERT en la base de datos
    Sub PINSERT()
        DataDate = DateAndTime.Year(DTPFecha.Value) & "/" & DateAndTime.Month(DTPFecha.Value) & "/" & DateAndTime.Day(DTPFecha.Value)
        DataHour = DateAndTime.Hour(DTPHora.Value) & ":" & DateAndTime.Minute(DTPHora.Value) & ":" & DateAndTime.Second(DTPHora.Value)
        SQL = "INSERT INTO Programas (Programa, WebSite, Instalado, Imagen, Fecha, Hora) SELECT '" & TxBProgr.Text & "', '" & TxBWSite.Text & "', " & ChBInsta.CheckState & ", '" & Imagen & "', '" & DataDate & "', '" & DataHour & "'"
        CDB.Operaciones(DGVDatos, SQL)
    End Sub
End Class
```

La interfaz de usuario que realizé es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber que hacer a continuación para así guardar la imagen, he realizado intentos de varios tipos para verficar si puedo o no hacer el INSERT de la imagen dentro de la base de datos, pero el Visual Studio en el acto me ha saltado detección de errores en cada uno de ellos.

Gracias por su tiempo, y agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionarme.